# How to completely close a view controller after returning to home view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have an iOS app consists of three view controllers

homeViewController -> newGameSelectionViewController -> GameViewController

In `GameViewController`, I have a "home" button that should close the view controller and return to the `newGameSelectionViewController`.

In `newGameSelectionViewController`,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    gameVC = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
    gameVC.countdown = 60
}
```

Then, I created an unwind `segue` to `newGameSelectionViewController` from `GameViewController`.

In newGameSelectionViewController,

```
@IBAction func unwindFromHomeButton(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    gameVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I press the home button in `GameViewController`, view closes and returns to the `newGameSelectionViewController`

The problem is, after pressing the home button and returning to the `newGameSelectionViewController`, countdown timer in `GameView` controller still continues. If I open an another `GameViewController`, it also open a completely new view controller. In another words, first `GameViewController` did not close by calling `dismissViewController()`. How do I close the `ViewController` completely so that if I start a new game, previous view controller does not continue counting at the background.

I am printing the countdown values with `println()` in `GameViewController`. Thats where I see the previous countdown values are still printing after `dismissViewController()`

Comment: You should disable timer in viewWillDisappear if you want to stop it as soon as it is about to disappear or in viewDidDisappear to make sure the view is gone when you disable timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gameVC` variable will be holding a strong reference to the `GameViewController` instance, so even though it has been dismissed, the object still exists as its reference count is not 0.

You need to set `gameVC` to nil in your unwind method in order to remove this reference.

```
@IBAction func unwindFromHomeButton(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    gameVC=nil;
}
```

You don't need to dismiss the view controller explicitly in the unwind method if you are correctly invoking it via a segue - The unwind process will do this for you.

Comment: I dragged the button to "Exit" pin of the GameViewController, then created the unwind segue. In newGameSelectionViewController, I erased the dismissViewController() and only set to gameVC to nil. Then, After I press the home button, GameViewController is dismissed successfully, but the counter values are still being printed. Starting a new GameView is also starting a new countdown timer. With the previous counter, two separate counters are still printed. So, the view controller is still working. Did I miss something while implementing the unwind segue?

Comment: You must have a reference to the game view controller somewhere else. Perhaps even a retain cycle inside the view controller itself. In the prepareForSegue method of the game view controller make sure you invalidate the timer as you unwind.